# Is it possible to retrieve query string params in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have an ActiveAdmin project that the user needs to select a category from a main page. They are then sent to a new product page with the category_id in the url (...blah?category_id=1) I want to be able to retrieve that category_id from the url. I keep getting an ActiveAdmin DSL error saying I can't params method

...blah?category_id=1

```
ActiveAdmin.register Product do

  controller do

    puts params[:category_id]

    def scoped_collection
      ItemsDesign.includes(:categories, :colors)
    end
  end
end
```

This what the AA controller should look like in order to get access to params.

```
  controller do
    def new
      @blah = Blah.new
      puts  params[:category_id]
    end
  end
```

Comment: can you show some code, that can help.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I the params needs to be inside an overriding method. In my case new as above.